# How to escape html encoding in detail template of kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with detail template. This is kendo MVC grid. I get some data from server which will have html text.

lets say parent grid data is like this "`<span class='text-red'>Test</span>`"

In parent grid I am binding this column like this.

```
columns.Bound(m => m.Name).ClientTemplate("#if(Name=== ''){# - #}else{# #=Name# #}#");
```

This will give me output `Test`

In detail template of this grid I get some other data using child grid Read method which also has some html data. Let says child grid gets "`<span class='text-green'>Hi</span>`"

I am binding this data like this.

```
columns.Bound(m => m.ChildName).ClientTemplate("\\#if(ChildName== ''){\\# - \\#}else{\\# \\#=ChildName\\# \\#}\\#")
```

but this is giving me output as `<span class='text-green'>Hi</span>`but I want output as just `Hi`. Why it is showing entire html? Why not it treat same as parent grid? I want the text `Hi` with css applied just like parent grid

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The child grid Read call encoding the html. I am getting data as `"&lt;span class=&#x27;&#x27;&gt;Test&lt;/span&gt;"` etc. So I modified child grid clientTemplate to call java-script function which will give correct data.

```
columns.Bound(m => m.ChildName).ClientTemplate("\\#=escapeNameEncode(ChildName)\\#")
```

JavaScript function

```
    escapeNameEncode(name: string) {

        if ($.trim(name) == '') {
            return '-';
        } else {
            var decodedString = $('<div>').html(name).text();
            return decodedString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set .Encoded(false) to your drill down column:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.ChildName).ClientTemplate("\\#if(ChildName== ''){\\# - \\#}else{\\# \\#=ChildName\\# \\#}\\#").Encoded(false)
```